# Shared libSDL library fails to open

Tags: shared-library, sdl

I'm having an issue with a shared library called libsdl. What I'm trying to do actually is to start up a game engine called GCCG (Generic Collectible Card Game). All the necessary packages were installed for the engine, however when I run the command `./Mtg` it gives me the following:

> ./ccg_client: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

From the error message, it seems clear that the libSDL libraries are either not installed or they cannot be accessed/are miss-located. After checking my packages with `dpkg --get-selections | grep libsdl` I found out that all the libSDL packages are installed... so just to make sure, I used `sudo apt-get purge` on all of the libSDL packages and made a clean install on all of the libSDL packages, however, the result is still the same.

Furthermore, when I use `apt-file search libSDL-1.2.so.0`, to locate the so-called "missing libraries", I get this as a result:

> libsdl1.2debian: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
>
> libsdl1.2debian: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3

So, as I figure it, they are there... but they are not shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a 32 bits or a 64 bits binary ? ( you can check with file ./Mtg ).

If this is a 32 bits binary, then you need the 32 bits version of libSDL, as you seems to be running x86_64.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you so much... I checked the game's client with the ***file [client_file]*** command and indeed, it was a 32bit binary.
So I installed all the libSDL 32bit equivalent libs and it worked out just great. 
Thank you again for the tip... now I know about the FILE command... I'm new to Linux. =)>

Answer (score 0):

I needed all those libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
sudo apt-get install libsdl-net1.2:i386
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2:i386
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
```