# ScreenCloud problem Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, screen

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I noticed that ScreenCloud is not anymore in the default repositories, so I went and downloaded the .deb file frome the official website, but when i try to install it, it says that the "libqtsingleapplication" can't be found....how do I install it?? ....on 13.04 it was working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install these packages from amd64 or i386 folders from [here](http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_13.10/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got it installed, but now I get `error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` even if sdl 1.2 (and also the -dev) are installed

Comment: @Sylar, may be http://askubuntu.com/questions/143393/shared-libsdl-library-fails-to-open or http://askubuntu.com/questions/201202/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsdl-1-2-so-0 ?

Answer (score 4):

From the ScreenCloud github: https://github.com/olav-st/screencloud/issues/8

Instructions here: http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Aolav-st&package=screencloud

tl;dr:

For xUbuntu 13.10 run the following as root:

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:olav-st/xUbuntu_13.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screencloud.list 
apt-get update
apt-get install screencloud
```

You can add the repository key to apt like this:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:olav-st/xUbuntu_13.10/Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
```

Comment: This works for me in 14.04 as well.